# How to get the rendered template from django?-pdfkit

Tags: django-templates, pdfkit

I have a template in my django application and I need to get it rendered in a variable or save it in an html file.

My goal is to convert the html rendering of the template to pdf, I am using pdfkit since it is the best html to pdf converter I have seen, reportlab does not do what I want.

When I try to do something like this:

```
pdf = pdfkit.from_file ('app / templates / app / table.html', 'table.pdf')
```

I get the pdf but print something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLvsZ.png)

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution to my case that I use django 2.0.1 and pdfkit 0.6.1:

To obtain the template:

```
template = get_template ('plapp / person_list.html')
```

To render it with the data:

```
html = template.render ({'persons': persons})
```

To continuation the definition of the method in views.py, the one that downloads the pdf directly in the browser:

```
def pdf(request):
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    template = get_template('plapp/person_list.html')
    html = template.render({'persons': persons})
    options = {
        'page-size': 'Letter',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
    }
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options)
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;
    filename="pperson_list_pdf.pdf"'
    return response
```

Comment: This is the right answer **ONLY IF** you don't have links to your images in your template. Otherwise, don't use this method. Images are only loaded in the PDF when you do `pdfkit.from_file`.

Comment: `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="pperson_list_pdf.pdf"'` should be in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.template.loader import get_template, render_to_string
```

Use the above to import functions that return the template. `get_template` returns the template object while `render_to_string` returns the string of a rendered template. Here's how I do it using weasyprint not pdfkit though.

```
def weasy_pdf_generation(request, id):
    # my data
    _, _, draft_details = get_draft_details('setup', request, id)
    radios_dict = {k:v[1] for k,v in draft_details.items()}
    # rendering to string
    html_template = render_to_string('tax/setupreview report.html', radios_dict)
    styles = CSS(url="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css")
    pdf_file = HTML(string=html_template).write_pdf(stylesheets=[styles])

    #response details
    response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="home_page.pdf"'
return response
```

Comment: Thanks machazthegamer!